# Cant render with fake array ReactJS/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

For some reason this wont render on the screen 10 times, it only renders out once.

```
{[Array(10)].map((e,i)=>{
                    return(
                        <div key={i} className="w-[250px] slide flex align-center p-[15px]">
                            <img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2560px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"} alt={"a"} />
                        </div>);
                })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to only render item with fake array why not use this simple approach

```
export function App(props) {
  let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

  return (
    <div className='App'>
     {
       arr.map((item,index) => (<div key={index} className="w-[250px] slide flex align-center p-[15px]">
            <img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2560px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"} alt={"a"} />
        </div>))
     }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked, for some reason both solutions above stil didnt work for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. Use

```
Array(10).fill(null).map((_, index)=>{
    return(
        <div key={index} className="w-[250px] slide flex align-center p-[15px]">
            <img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2560px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"} alt={"a"} />
        </div>);
})}
```

The first issue is that you're making a nested/two dimensional array, by wrapping your array in square brackets:

```
[Array(10)]
```

So you need to omit the square brackets.

The second issue is a nightmare of Javascript, where an array instantiated with `Array(size)` has a magical "empty" property, so it can't be iterated over. You need to fill each element with something, so you need `.fill(null)` or any other dummy value.

Comment: Can you give an example of how I can implement ```.fill(null)```

Comment: @GunvirDhesi `.fill` is a [standard array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: @GunvirDhesi by copy-pasting the posted code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `keys` with spread syntax:

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map(...)
```